# How to avoid selecting objects on the "other side of the PCB" in Altium?

Tags: altium

In Altium whenever I try to place chunks of finished circuit on the bottom layer, top-layer components are still visible and selectable. I have tried the following:

1. Locking components, just provokes a prompt from Altium whenever I happen to unwillingly select them anyway. And they are still visible.
2. View-configuration lets me disable most of top-layer-stuff, but some mechanical layers seem to be visible on both layers. And seem to still make them selectable.
3. PCB-filter, "works" but now I can't select my rooms. No matter if I select/deselect rooms in the filter or choose top/bottom-layer.
4. Moving chunks of circuits by selecting and drag and drop, leaves my tracks hanging(even though they are neither locked or "not selected"
5. Cut/Paste works, but now all "connections" seem to be lost even though they are still connected with tracks.

Any advice would be much appreciated.

Comment: These questions seem to cover no questions about electronics, just about basic use of the program. These are better suited in the dedicated forum, but should be explained in beginner tutorials as well. To give two hints: use single layer mode, and never do copy and paste of components.

Comment: Go into the 'layers' menu and make any layers on the bottom invisible.  I setup layer stack sets to quickly toggle the views.  It's not hard to figure out once you find that menu.

Comment: Yes, hide the layers from which you do not want to select.

Comment: Ups sorry, couuld you point me in the direction to the dedicated forum?

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you may want to use single layer mode. To enter this mode use the shortcut Shift S. Pressing this combination once simply grays out the background layers, pressing twice hides all but the active layer. Pressing a third time returns to normal. When you are in single-layer mode, you can only select objects on the active layer.

Comment: Thx! My main concern at the moment is the rough placement of big components and subcircuits. When I choose single layer, components dissaper all but their pads. And I need the component outline for placing. If i Choose the component outline layer, I loose the ability to select them (no selection filter/pcb-filter added)

Comment: In that case you'll probably need to set up a layer set including all of the layers you want visible (i.e. top copper, top silkscreen, component outline, etc). Then when you display that layer set, all layers except those included in the layer set are hidden. You can access the layer set creation tool from the View Configuration panel under the Layers & Colors tab. See "Layers & Colors" tab --> "Layers" on this webpage: https://www.altium.com/documentation/altium-designer/pcb-colors-visibility